# Java regex that does NOT contain group

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex that matches everything but floating point numbers.
The regex for a floating number would be like this:

```
String floatPat = "(?:\\d+\\.\\d+)";
```

How would I use that to NOT match a floating number? I can't use a caret ^ like I use for class definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\d+\\.\\d+).*
```

This expression would match anything (`.*`) unless it is preceded by a match of your float regex (non-capturing).

Comment: Would I need to add a negative lookahead for that as well? Also, why doesn't using a zero quantifier work? Ex: (?:(?:\\d+\\.\\d+){0})+

Comment: @GeorgeNewton Since the expression `.*` matches literally anything, a lookbehind is sufficient. Using zero quantifier says "match XYZ zero times" which is another way of saying "match an empty string", so regex engine says "OK, done, what's next?" and moves on.

Comment: To expand on this a bit: the quantifiers are positive only, in that they tell the matcher what to match, but don't tell it to fail.  So, if your regex is `a{2,4}` and your source string is `"aaaaa"` (5 a's), the matcher will match four of the a's (greedy mode), but it will not fail just because there's a fifth "a" there.  Instead, the fifth "a" just doesn't get consumed by `a{2,4}`.